# I want to do user finder using python django

Tags: python, django

```
class ForgotidAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = ForgotidSerualizer
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        Email = request.data.getlist('email')
        First_name = request.data.getlist('first_name')
        test = User.objects.get(email=Email)
        print('e-mail : ', Email);
        print('your name' : , First_name);
        print('test : ', test)

        
        return Response(
                    {
                        "email": "test",
                        "first_name": "test",
                    }
                )
```

I would like to compare the saved emails to the emails I sent and print the user accordingly.

Only the statement'test = User.objects.get (email = Email)' is not executed. How do you run it?

Comment: `test = User.objects.filter(email=Email)` replace your line with this one and see... if there is same error or not?

Comment: Thank you infinitely, I will delete the comment.

Comment: Did it work then?

Comment: It worked, but it seems I can't compare the values ​​due to the wrong data type, this is what I'll fix. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem is strange and  it was solved by using `filter()` in place of `get()`. So:

```
test = User.objects.filter(email=Email)
```

@handsomecode *Don't use capitalize letter as variable as you did for `Email = request.data.getlist('email')` it's a bad practice, define variables with lowercase letters.*